# AngularJS - Validate only if one field greater than the other

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, input-field

I have two input fields, one is the `From Year` and the other is `To Year`. I have to validate the submit button of the form only if `To Year` is greater than the `From Year` value.

This is the code for from year:

```
<div class="col-md-6 no-pad-right">
 <label>Tenure From Year</label>
 <input name="tenure_from_year" ng-model="joinFormData.tenureFromYear" name="tenure_from_year" class="form-control" placeholder="2014" type="text" ng-required="joinFormData.memberType == 'alumni'" ng-maxlength="4" ng-pattern="/(?:(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})/">
 <span ng-show="joinForm.tenure_from_year.$error.pattern || joinForm.tenure_from_year.$error.maxlength">
    <span class="red-color">Enter correct year!</span>
 </span>
</div>
```

This is the code for to year:

```
<div class="col-md-6 no-pad-right">
  <label>Tenure To Year</label>
 <input name="tenure_to_year" ng-model="joinFormData.tenureToYear" name="tenure_to_year" class="form-control" placeholder="2014" type="text" ng-required="joinFormData.memberType == 'alumni'" ng-maxlength="4" ng-pattern="/(?:(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})/">
 <span ng-show="joinForm.tenure_to_year.$error.pattern || joinForm.tenure_to_year.$error.maxlength">
  <span class="red-color">Enter correct year! </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

The submit button is disabled if the form is invalid

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-save-custom"  ng-click="joinLeap()" ng-disabled="joinForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>
```

So how can I validate the from and to year fields so that it enables the submit button when the years are valid.

Comment: this did not work. I added a function to check if to is greater than from and set validity to true. But it didn't work @tanmay

Answer (score 0):

you can use watch .

```
$scope.validate = false;
$scope.$watch('joinFormData.tenureFromYear', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal > oldVal) {
     $scope.validate = true;
  } else {
     $scope.validate = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare both the `ng-model` field inside method `joinLeap()` which you have mentioned in `ng-click`

```
$scope.dateValidation = false;

$scope.joinLeap = function (joinFormData) {
   if (joinFormData.tenureToYear > joinFormData.tenureFromYear) {
      $scope.dateValidation = true;
   } else {
      $scope.dateValidation = false;
   }
}
```

Pass the parameter through `ng-click` method

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-save-custom"  ng-click="joinLeap(joinFormData)" ng-disabled="joinForm.$invalid || !dateValidation" >Submit</button>
```

I guess this will help you. set the true, false value for dateValidation as per requirement.